# List of class items in python

Tags: python, list, class, configparser

I'm trying to create a list of my class items from a following configuration file (named Config.ini in my code)

```
[name1]
type=1
value=1
[name2]
type=1
value=2
[name3]
type=2
value=3
```

with following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import configparser

class Switch:
    Name = ""
    Value = 0
    Type = ""

config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('Config.ini')

mySwitches = list()

for e in config.sections():
    s = Switch()
    s.Name = e
    for name, value in config.items(e):
        if name=="type":
            s.Type = value
        elif name=="value":
            s.Value = value
    mySwitches.append(s)
    
for s in mySwitches:
    print (s.Name)
```

But I get a list of last read config items. I believe I need to construct new class instance in each iteration of for loop... But how.

Comment: What is the expected result from your code?

Comment: You are creating a new instance every iteration. The reason you're only seeing the names is you are only printing the names in your last loop. Just `print(s)` and you'll see they are all different instances of `Switch`

Comment: @Pavel - do you have to use ini file or you can use other format?

Comment: On my computer, your code is correct, there is no problem, the 3 values in `mySwitches` have the 3 different properties from `Config.ini`

Comment: @Shimon I had a list of three instances of the last added one. But was expecting three.

Comment: @Jab thanks, I added "_" to variable names as tutorials offers as well

Comment: @fusion it's just a package I found to be used with configuration files. Any recommendations?